# Convert string to number and count sum of values in an array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to sum total of amount with the type string in array so I write this in mongo. any help please

**Tried :**

```
db.compte.aggregate([
 {$project:{
   account: "$auditMessages.eventMetaData.Counterparty Name",
   amount: "$auditMessages.eventMetaData.Transaction Amount",
   "total": {$sum:"$amount"}
 }}])
```

**The result:**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ed638e566a699750cbb1b0f"),
"account" : [
  "Mr Jalel CHAHED",
  "Mr Jalel CHAHED",
  "Mr Jalel CHAHED",
  "Mr Jalel CHAHED"
 ],
"amount" :
 [ 
  "4.32",
  "4.32",
   "1.32",
   "1.32"
 ],
"total" : 0}
```

Comment: What is the issue with current query? What is the current result? What is the expected result?

Comment: I want to sum total of amount, sum is 11.28 (4.32+4.32+1.32+1.32) but the total is 0

Comment: This should be easy just group by id or main column here and then do sum on amount. You will need another pipeline maybe. As we don't know what the `compte` collection look like we can't provide any specific solution to this question.

Comment: I used group by, the same result total 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating `amount` field in `$project` and using it in same stage there itself which is why it's returning `0` on `"total": {$sum:"$amount"}`, also `$sum` seems to not take arrays.

Assuming your documents look like :

```
{
    "auditMessages": {
      eventMetaData: [
        {
          "Counterparty Name": "Mr Jalel CHAHED",
          abc: 1,
          "Transaction Amount": "4.32"
        },
        {
          "Counterparty Name": "Mr Jalel CHAHED",
          abc: 11,
          "Transaction Amount": "4.32"
        },
        {
          "Counterparty Name": "Mr Jalel CHAHED",
          abc: 12,
          "Transaction Amount": "1.32"
        },
        {
          "Counterparty Name": "Mr Jalel CHAHED",
          abc: 122,
          "Transaction Amount": "1.32"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

As `auditMessages.eventMetaData` is an array then when you do :

`"$auditMessages.eventMetaData.Counterparty Name"` or `"$auditMessages.eventMetaData.Transaction Amount"` then what you get is an array of values like what you see in your result as of now.

**Query :**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
      $project: {
        account: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$auditMessages.eventMetaData.Counterparty Name", 0 ] }, // get name from first element in array,use only if name is same in all objects
        total: {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$auditMessages.eventMetaData.Transaction Amount", // Iterate on array
            initialValue: 0,
            in: { $trunc: [ { $add: [ "$$value", { $toDouble: "$$this" } ] }, 2 ] } // convert string to double, sum-up & truncate to 2 digits
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tJT3dVR8mwQ)

**Ref :** [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)

Comment: how can get one name for example name Mr Jalel CHAHED and the total number is 4 
thank you!

Comment: @m1h3r: Didn't get what you mean by !